# Why this regular expression doesn't validate

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a regular expression for check strings like **G20003030** or like **G-20003030**. The first letter can be any of this: VGJ. This is my code:

```
$string = "G20003030";
if (preg_match('^[VGJ]{1,1}?[0-9]{8,8}$/', $string)) {
    echo "passed";
} else {
    echo "not passed";
}
```

But all the time it returns "not passed". What's wrong in my regular expression and how to check both variants? (I think my code only works for the first one)

Comment: You're not checking for the optional dash.

Comment: Couldn't that be simplified to `/^[VGJ]-?\d{8}$/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Warning**: `preg_match()`: No ending delimiter `'^'` found in /code/xxxxxx.php on line 3

You forgot the first slash and the hyphen (thanks **@Sepster**).

```
/^[VGJ]-?[0-9]{8}$/
```

Comment: Also needs (optional) hyphen.

Comment: @Florent thanks it works perfectly and yes I miss the hyphen at first :(

Answer (score 2):

try using this regex:

```
/^[VGJ]-?[0-9]{8}$/
```